# How could I ping @here in Discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I want to figure out how I can make my bot ping @here since I know how to make it ping @everyone. I am trying to make a bump system for my shop server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply send `"@here"`

```py
await messageable.send("@here")
```

Comment: I overcomplicated it lmao. Thank you!